# Beginner trying to learn inheritance with game programming

Tags: c++, inheritance, sfml

I'm trying to make a framework for an SFML game I'm making and I'm having trouble with inheritance. I thought I knew how to do it but it doesn't seem right. I want my main to just call GameLoop basically and thats it. In my GameLoop class I have methods for making the window and running the game. Then I want my GamePlayScreen class to actually handle the game logic but for some reason I can't figure out how to inherit from GameLoop. I was watching a video and the guy was using C# which is why I'm having trouble converting it. The video is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WhbeqOOSDEo&index=2&list=PLfTDIoEcaNroztBVGPA0aU3NbOauRVIe3.

GameLoop.h

```
#pragma once
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <string>

class GameLoop
{
public:
    GameLoop(int width, int height, std::string title);
    virtual void Run();
    virtual void LoadContent();
    virtual void Initialize();
    virtual void Update();
    virtual void Render();

    sf::RenderWindow window;
};
```

GameLoop.cpp

```
#include "GameLoop.h"


GameLoop::GameLoop(int width, int height, std::string title)
{
    window = sf::RenderWindow(sf::VideoMode(width, height), title, sf::Style::Default);
}


void GameLoop::Run()
{
    LoadContent();
    Initialize();

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;

        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        Update();
        window.clear();
        Render();
        window.display();
    }
}

void GameLoop::LoadContent()
{

}

void GameLoop::Initialize()
{

}

void GameLoop::Update()
{

}

void GameLoop::Render()
{

}
```

GamePlayScreen.h

```
#pragma once
#include "GameLoop.h"
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

class GamePlayScreen : public GameLoop
{
public:
    GamePlayScreen();
    void Initialize();

};
```

GamePlayScreen.cpp

```
#include "GamePlayScreen.h"

GamePlayScreen::GameLoop(800, 600, "Game");
{

}

void GamePlayScreen::Initialize()
{
    GameLoop game(800, 600, "Game");
}
```

Comment: What's the trouble? Do you get a compiler error? A runtime herror?

Comment: Read [ask] and then compare the guidelines there with your question.

Comment: I just don't know how to do it. I was messing with it in GamePlayScreen but really had no idea how to call the methods or constructor.

Comment: It seems odd for `GamePlayScreen` to inherit from `GameLoop` in the first place. That doesn't make sense because a screen is not a loop. `GamePlayScreen::GameLoop(800, 600, "Game");{}` <-- I don't know what that's supposed to do, but it's not valid syntax.

Comment: Inheritance is a "is-a" relationship. For example, a dragon "is-a" monster, therefore it makes sense for a possible `Dragon` class to inherit from a possible `Monster` class. You also need to learn the difference between [inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_%28object-oriented_programming%29) and [composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition), and when to use one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor will be called automatically when you 'new' the class. Just make a matching constructor in GamePlayScreen and the system will call the derived constructor first - but the signature must match.

```
class GamePlayScreen : public GameLoop
{
public:
    GamePlayScreen();
    GamePlayScreen(int width, int height, std::string title);
    void Initialize();

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not a real answer but I can not comment.
As I can see main subject is about "Handling Multiple Screens".
So you may look at this tutorial: https://github.com/SFML/SFML/wiki/Tutorial:-Manage-different-Screens